# adding image and folder rename to kendo UI file manager

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm using kendo UI file manager to browse in my files and images. I've read in telerik documents that only add folder and remove files and folder is supported. but I need to add the ability to rename files and folders. is there anyway to add this to file manager?

Answer (score 0):

```
var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");

editor.toolbar.element.find(".k-insertImage").parent().click(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      var imageBrowser = $(".k-imagebrowser").data("kendoImageBrowser");
      imageBrowser.listView.bind("dataBound", function(e){
         if (imageBrowser._path == "/") {
            imageBrowser.element.find(".k-toolbar-wrap").hide();
         } else {
            imageBrowser.element.find(".k-toolbar-wrap").show();
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: could you please add some explanation to your answer?